# Highlight parts of text selected by user in flutter

Tags: flutter, text, highlight

So, i'm working on an annotation app with flutter. The user selects a range of text in a selectableText Field and that text has to be highlighted. I'm using selectableText widget to get selected text.Is there a way?

This is a screenshot of what i'm trying to do.
Every highlighted part of text is a text that the user already selected and assigned a tag to.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/33qCL.png

So far, i've found this code that allows to highlight one selection :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class HighlightText extends StatelessWidget {
 final String text;
 final String highlight;
 final TextStyle style;
 final TextStyle highlightStyle;
 final Color highlightColor;
 final bool ignoreCase;

 HighlightText({
   Key key,
   this.text,
   this.highlight,
   this.style,
   this.highlightColor,
   TextStyle highlightStyle,
   this.ignoreCase: false,
 })  : assert(
         highlightColor == null || highlightStyle == null,
         'highlightColor and highlightStyle cannot be provided at same time.',
       ),
       highlightStyle = highlightStyle ?? style?.copyWith(color: highlightColor) ?? TextStyle(color: highlightColor),
       super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final text = this.text ?? '';
   if ((highlight?.isEmpty ?? true) || text.isEmpty) {
     return Text(text, style: style);
   }

   var sourceText = ignoreCase ? text.toLowerCase() : text;
   var targetHighlight = ignoreCase ? highlight.toLowerCase() : highlight;

   List<TextSpan> spans = [];
   int start = 0;
   int indexOfHighlight;
   do {
     indexOfHighlight = sourceText.indexOf(targetHighlight, start);
     if (indexOfHighlight < 0) {
       // no highlight
       spans.add(_normalSpan(text.substring(start)));
       break;
     }
     if (indexOfHighlight > start) {
       // normal text before highlight
       spans.add(_normalSpan(text.substring(start, indexOfHighlight)));
     }
     start = indexOfHighlight + highlight.length;
     spans.add(_highlightSpan(text.substring(indexOfHighlight, start)));
   } while (true);

   return Text.rich(TextSpan(children: spans));
 }

 TextSpan _highlightSpan(String content) {
   return TextSpan(text: content, style: highlightStyle);
 }

 TextSpan _normalSpan(String content) {
   return TextSpan(text: content, style: style);
 }
}
```

And i'm trying to adapt it so that i can highlight multiple parts.

Comment: You are talking about selecting text in textfield, than why are you using SelectableText?

Comment: My mistake. It's a SelectableText widget. I found no way to get selected text from a textField.

Comment: Are you not able to highlight text in TextField using Long Press?

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you;ve tried so far?